# Is it permissible to redraw characters that are created previously

Tags: halal-haram, image, drawing

Is it haram to draw a face or a character or an animal that's from a book or a show or a movie something that's basically already created but you're drawing it on a different canvas your drawing the same thing that's already created but on your piece of paper or your canvas I want to know clearly if it's haram or not because I have heard that it is if you're creating a random character but I have not heard if it is, or isn't if you're drawing a character that's already created.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum, I encourage you to weigh all different advice, interpretations and opinions in the matter and ask Allah swt for guidance. I am not qualified to tell you what it is right. Watch Dr Shabir Ally's answer in the *video_link* below, he also gives interesting historic context of where the hadith may have come from:

[Q&A: What's the Ruling on Drawing? | Dr. Shabir Ally](https://youtu.be/LJVfAba_jtc)

Also here is more research regarding the hadiths and scholars who have the opinion that it is permissible:

1. [The evidence for the permissibly of drawing and painting in Islam](https://hawramani.com/the-evidence-for-the-permissibly-of-drawing-and-painting-in-islam/)
2. [Is it haram to hang pictures in a room?](https://hawramani.com/is-it-haram-to-hang-pictures-in-a-room/)

There is most caution about hanging any of these pictures up on the wall as this can be in line with worshipping the images, this is the main area of prohibition!

Answer (score -1):

According to the following hadis, drawing humans or animals are haram.

> **Narrated 'Aisha :**
> I purchased a cushion with pictures on it. The Prophet (came and) stood at the door but did not enter. I said (to him), "I repent to Allah for what (the guilt) I have done." He said, "What is this cushion?" I said, "It is for you to sit on and recline on." He said, "The makers of these pictures will be punished on the Day of Resurrection and it will be said to them, 'Make alive what you have created.' Moreover, the angels do not enter a house where there are pictures.'"

[*Peace be upon  Prophet Muhammad and may Allah be pleased on 'Aisha*]